# function for randomizing (row-wise) df, splitting, then writing to csv

Tags: r, function, dataframe, variable-assignment

So, my goal is to write a function that will take as input any csv file, an output path, and an arbitrary number of split sizes (by number of rows), and then randomize and split the data into the appropriate files. I could really easily do this manually if I know the split sizes ahead of time, but I want an automated function that will handle varying split sizes. Seems straightforward, and here's what I had written:

```
randomizer = function(startFile, endPath, ...){ ##where ... are the user-defined split sizes

           vec = unlist(list(...))

           n_files = length(vec)

           values = read.csv(startFile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

           values_rand = as.data.frame(values[sample(nrow(values)),])

           for(i in 1:n_files){
              if(nrow(values_rand)!=0 & !is.null(nrow(values_rand))){
              assign(paste('group', i , sep=''), values_rand[1:vec[i], ]);
              values_rand = as.data.frame(values_rand[(vec[i]+1):nrow(values_rand), ], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
              ## (A) write.csv fn here?
                 } else {
               print("something went wrong")
                }
            }
## (B) write.csv fn here?
}
  }
```

when I try to do something in place (A) like  `write.csv(x= paste('group', i, sep=''), file= paste(endPath, '/group', i, '.csv', sep=''), row.names=FALSE`  I get errors or literally writing the string "group1" to a csv, rather than the chunk of the randomized dataframe i'm looking for. I'm super confused, as this seems like I'm running up against R semantics rather than a genuine programming issue.. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can we assume that if the split sizes do not evenly partition the data, that your function will simply stop and return nothing but a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed programmed yourself into a corner here, and it's a common one for beginners to end up in, particularly beginners that are coming to R from other programming languages.

The use of `assign` is the big red flag. At least when you're starting out in the language, if you feel yourself reaching for that function, stop and think again. You're most likely approaching the problem entirely wrong and need to rethink it.

Here is my (entirely untested) version of what you described, annotated with some comments:

```
split_file <- function(startFile,endPath,sizes){
    #There's no need to use "..." for the partition sizes.
    # A simple vector of values is much simpler

    values <- read.csv(startFile,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    if (sum(sizes) != nrow(values)){
        #I'm assuming here that we're not doing anything fancy with bad input
        stop("sizes do not evenly partition data!")
    }else{
        #Shuffle data frame
        # Note we don't need as.data.frame()
        values <- values[sample(nrow(values)),]

        #Split data frame
        values <- split(values,rep(seq_len(nrow(values)),times = sizes))
        #Create the output file paths
        paths <- paste0(endPath,"/group_",seq_along(sizes))
        #We could shoe-horn this into lapply, but there's no real need
        for (i in seq_along(values)){
            write.csv(x = values[[i]],file = paths[i],row.names = FALSE)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, joran, your answer got me where I wanted to go. The one change that needs to be made is the <code>split</code> function's factor argument. I.e., instead of <code>rep(seq_len(nrow(values)), times=sizes</code>, use <code>rep(seq_len(length(sizes)), times=sizes</code>.

Obviously, your solutions works well and seems relatively R-like, and while it solved this problem, I'd like to steer away from such obvious misdirection in future R projects. Anything in particular you suggest I do to start thinking in R rather than other languages?